# Stored Procedure is faster the 2nd time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am running SP on SQL Server 2017

The first time I executed the SP it took 43 sec

but the 2nd time it took 1 sec only

How can I execute the SP everytime same as the first time without cache or any learning from the previous experience?

I am not asking why, as this question wants to know Why this is happening 
[First run slowness in a sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995873/first-run-slowness-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

I am asking, How to make it the same as the first time.

I want my procedure everytime it executes as if its the first time

Comment: Is it running slow since the second execution?

Comment: @SalmanA it is running faster since the 2nd time, i was slower in the 1st time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First run slowness in a sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995873/first-run-slowness-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: Not uncommon. The first time it ran it had to create an execution plan, the second time it was cached. Data could already been in memory, etc.

Comment: You can try recompiling the query every time using `option(recompile)`

Comment: *"I want my procedure everytime it executes as if its the first time"* Why do you want your SP to take 43 seconds to run everytime? Isn't faster better..?

Comment: Faster is better for sure, but for training purposes I want to get the initial state

Comment: @EzLo  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE did the job, plz make it an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove stored plan caches, you can execute [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Just beware that it will get a clean slate for all stored procedures.

Remember that once the plan is compiled, it will be stored for future calls until either the SP gets altered or a dependent object is also modified. So most of the times what you want to test is actually the performance of the already compiled plan, unless you constantly are clearing these caches, restarting the servers or triggering a recompile somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

prior to each execution. This will clear the buffer pool so that the playing field is leveled and each iteration will incur roughly the same IO overhead.

Also see [Performance testing with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](https://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/) for additional considerations for measuring performance with this method.